# How to unarchive data in swift 3?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an app where I save an array of `CNContact` to `UserDefaults` as such:

```
var contactsArray = [CNContact]()
let defaults = UserDefaults()
func (contact: CNContact){
    contactsArray.append(contact)
    let contactArrayArchive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: contactArray) //archive the data
    defaults.set(contactArrayArchive, forKey: "contactArray")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

This archives the data to allow it to be saved to `defaults`. My issue is with how I can convert this data back to an array of `CNContact` in the `viewDidLoad`. I have seen many answers online which suggest to use `NSKeyedArchiver.unarchiveObjectwithData` but typing this into Xcode, with swift 3, says that the `.unarchiveObjectwithData` is not a member of `NSKeyedArchiver`. I keep looking for stuff about how to do this in swift 3 but have been unsuccessful. How can I unarchive the value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
 NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: Data)
```

You have Used **NSKeyedArchiver** . You cannot use this to unarchive an Object.

Answer (score 3):

If you press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> to open the documentation and type <kbd>nsk</kbd> (3 characters are sufficient) you will see

[image]

To **un**archive something you need the NSKeyed**Un**archiver